# Is Baba Yaga always the antagonist, or sometimes the protagonist?

Tags: slavic, baba-yaga

I ask because I only know her from folktales, children's plays, and secondary sources, but the general impression I formed was of Baba Yaga as the protagonist. Is this incorrect or is she sometimes the hero of stories?

Answer (score 9):

To my knowledge Baba Yaga was never the *Hero* (the character who we typically refer to as the protagonist) in any of the stories I have heard. Nevertheless, here is an academic reference that I've found while looking it up since this piqued my interest. 
Your answer lies at the bottom.

Vladimir Propp was a Soviet folklorist and scholar who analyzed the basic plot components of Russian folk tales to identify their simplest irreducible narrative elements.

He concluded that all the characters could be resolved into 7 broad character functions in the 100 tales he analyzed:

1. **The villain** — an evil character that creates struggles for the hero.
2. **The dispatcher** — any character who illustrates the need for the
   hero's quest and sends the hero off. This often overlaps with the
   princess's father.
3. **The helper** — a typically magical entity that comes to help the hero
   in their quest.
4. **The princess or prize**, and often her father — the hero deserves her
   throughout the story but is unable to marry her as a consequence of
   some evil or injustice, perhaps the work of the villain. The hero's
   journey is often ended when he marries the princess, which
   constitutes the villain's defeat.
5. **The donor** — a character that prepares the hero or gives the hero
   some magical object, sometimes after testing them.
6. **The hero** — the character who reacts to the dispatcher and donor
   characters, thwarts the villain, resolves any lacking or wronghoods
   and weds the princess.
7. **The false hero** — a Miles Gloriosus figure who takes credit for the
   hero's actions or tries to marry the princess.

According to Vladimir Propp's folktale morphology, ***Baba Yaga*** commonly appears as either a **donor** or **villain**, or may be altogether ambiguous.

Here is a link to a PDF version of his book I found online - [Morphology of the folktale](https://monoskop.org/images/f/f3/Propp_Vladimir_Morphology_of_the_Folktale_2nd_ed.pdf).

Comment: A great way to answer the question. In the general case, I wonder if we can't separate the McGuffin/false prize/red herring out of #4.